# Long ComboBox Text, Not Displayed Fully

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi anyone solve my problem regarding "exprect {" i dont know why i get this error. i hope you can help me whats wrong in this code.

Code:

```
   [DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    private readonly ToolTip ttp;

    public ComboBoxEx() : base() => ttp = new ToolTip();

    private bool _showItemToolTip = true;
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool ShowItemToolTip
    {
        get => _showItemToolTip;
        set
        {
            if (_showItemToolTip != value)
            {
                _showItemToolTip = value;
                ttp.SetToolTip(this, string.Empty);  
            }
        }
    }

protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);

    if (ShowItemToolTip)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;

        if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            var sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font);

            if (sz.Width > Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth)
                str = Text;
        }

        ttp.SetToolTip(this, str);
    }
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  

   

   {
            if (disposing) ttp.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I got error in this part of the code. anyone know why
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfsM9.png

Comment: vs2010 OK, `public ComboBoxEx() : base() { ttp = new ToolTip(); }` -- `get { return _showItemToolTip; }`

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` operator denotes an expression body. It's basically a shorthand that makes a one-line method or property getter or setter look like a lambda expression. It was introduced in a version of C# released much later than 2010. If you upgrade to a newer version of VS then you can use a C# language version that supports that syntax. If you want to stick with VS 2010, you need to use the old standard syntax. You already know what that is because you're already using it for the for multi-line bodies.

```cs
public ComboBoxEx() : base()
{
    ttp = new ToolTip();
}
```

```cs
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ShowItemToolTip
{
    get
    {
        return _showItemToolTip;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_showItemToolTip != value)
        {
            _showItemToolTip = value;
            ttp.SetToolTip(this, string.Empty);  
        }
    }
}
```